# Address out of bounds in C, problems with making an ls command

Tags: c, unix, terminal

I am trying to make a some what shell in C but I am having problems with making the `ls` command.  `mkdir`, and `cd` work fine but with `ls` it gives me

> "Address out of bounds segmentation error"

Hope somebody can help me. Here's my code.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main() {
    printf("\033[1;33mWelcome To Crisp Bacon Shell\n");
    while (1) {
        printf("\033[0m%s $", hostname);
        input = readline("");
        command = get_input(input);

        child_pid = fork();
         if (child_pid < 0) {
            perror("Fork failed");
            exit(1);
        }else if (child_pid == 0) {
            /* Never returns if the call is successful */
            execvp(command[0], command);
            printf("This won't be printed if execvp is successul\n");
        } else {
            waitpid(child_pid, &stat_loc, WUNTRACED);
        }

        free(input);
        free(command);
    }
    return 0;
}

char **get_input(char *input) {
    char **command = malloc(8 * sizeof(char *));
    char *separator = " ";
    char *parsed;
    int index = 0;

    parsed = strtok(input, separator);
    while (parsed != NULL) {
        command[index] = parsed;
        index++;

        parsed = strtok(NULL, separator);
    }

    command[index] = NULL;
    return command;
}
```

The only thing I understand it has something to do with memory and references or pointers but I tried changing everything from & refrencing to pointers and it just gave me more errors what do I do?

Comment: Step 1: `while (parsed != NULL)` --> `while (parsed != NULL && index < (8-1))`

Answer (score 0):

There were many undeclared variables in your code snippets. You also need to fetch the hostname, it isn't a global variable. It's also a best practice to declare your functions before using them.

This works fine:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

char **get_input(char *input) {
    char **command = malloc(8 * sizeof(char *));
    char *separator = " ";
    int index = 0;

    char *parsed = strtok(input, separator);
    while (parsed != NULL && index < 8) { // you need to make sure the index does not overflow the array
        command[index] = parsed;
        index++;

        parsed = strtok(NULL, separator);
    }

    command[index] = NULL;
    return command;
}

int main() {
    printf("\033[1;33mWelcome To Crisp Bacon Shell\n");
    while (1) {
        // hostname does not exist, you need to fetch it
        char hostname[1024];
        gethostname(hostname, 1023); // POSIX only
        printf("\033[0m%s $", hostname);
        char *input = readline(NULL);
        char **command = get_input(input);

        pid_t child_pid = fork();
        if (child_pid < 0) {
            perror("Fork failed");
            exit(1);
        } else if (child_pid == 0) {
            /* Never returns if the call is successful */
            execvp(command[0], command);
            printf("This won't be printed if execvp is successul\n");
        } else {
            waitpid(child_pid, NULL, WUNTRACED); // since you don't use the middle argument, no need to point to valid data
        }

        free(input);
        free(command);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Those are declared in my code it's just stackoverflow has a dumb thing where it won't let me post the whole code so i had to trim it alot

Comment: Also i tried this code and it does not work it still gives me "Address out of bounds error"